# Hows does a windows color get calculated from ARGB

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me how from an ARGB, the corresponding windows Color is calculated? I know there is a ColorTranslator.ToWin32() that does the calculation but how is it done?

Also, what is the difference between an OLE color and a windows (win32) color?

JD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour object in .NET includes an alpha channel (i.e. the level of transparency), while Win32 colours are purely RGB. So to convert between the two you want something like the following:

```
    static public int ConvertColourToWindowsRGB(Color dotNetColour)
    {
        int winRGB = 0;

        // windows rgb values have byte order 0x00BBGGRR
        winRGB |= (int)dotNetColour.R;
        winRGB |= (int)dotNetColour.G << 8;
        winRGB |= (int)dotNetColour.B << 16;

        return winRGB;
    }

    static public Color ConvertWindowsRGBToColour(int windowsRGBColour)
    {
        int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;

        // windows rgb values have byte order 0x00BBGGRR
        r = (windowsRGBColour & 0x000000FF);
        g = (windowsRGBColour & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        b = (windowsRGBColour & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;

        Color dotNetColour = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);

        return dotNetColour;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply John, is this what ColorTranslator.ToWin32()/FromWinW32() does? Also, what is OLE color?

JD.

Comment: Essentially yes - as Alexandre showed the disassembled code is very similar. The idea of OLE Color is that it can include a flag indicating that the colour is a system colour, such as "button face". Since these may appear differently on different operating systems/themes they would be useful if you want to make your application match the current windows theme. If they don't include a flag then they'll behave just like a Win32 colour.

Comment: Thank you John for the explanation. I have never had the use of bitwise and shift operations, so seeing your example has made me learn how to use them.

Also thanks to Alex below, I will try to use Reflector more in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Using an IL Disassembler (like Reflector), you can get the code for ColorTranslator.ToWin32(). Notice that the ToWin32 color doesn't use the alpha value.

```
public static int ToWin32(Color c)
{
    return ((c.R | (c.G << 8)) | (c.B << 0x10));
}
```

ColorTranslator.ToOle(...) is testing if the color is a standard system color otherwise, it's using ToWin32 conversion :

```
public static int ToOle(Color c)
{
    if (c.IsKnownColor)
    {
        switch (c.ToKnownColor())
        {
            case KnownColor.ActiveBorder:
                return -2147483638;

            case KnownColor.ActiveCaption:
                return -2147483646;

            case KnownColor.ActiveCaptionText:
                return -2147483639;

            case KnownColor.AppWorkspace:
                return -2147483636;

            case KnownColor.Control:
                return -2147483633;

            case KnownColor.ControlDark:
                return -2147483632;

            case KnownColor.ControlDarkDark:
                return -2147483627;

            case KnownColor.ControlLight:
                return -2147483626;

            case KnownColor.ControlLightLight:
                return -2147483628;

            case KnownColor.ControlText:
                return -2147483630;

            case KnownColor.Desktop:
                return -2147483647;

            case KnownColor.GrayText:
                return -2147483631;

            case KnownColor.Highlight:
                return -2147483635;

            case KnownColor.HighlightText:
                return -2147483634;

            case KnownColor.HotTrack:
                return -2147483635;

            case KnownColor.InactiveBorder:
                return -2147483637;

            case KnownColor.InactiveCaption:
                return -2147483645;

            case KnownColor.InactiveCaptionText:
                return -2147483629;

            case KnownColor.Info:
                return -2147483624;

            case KnownColor.InfoText:
                return -2147483625;

            case KnownColor.Menu:
                return -2147483644;

            case KnownColor.MenuText:
                return -2147483641;

            case KnownColor.ScrollBar:
                return -2147483648;

            case KnownColor.Window:
                return -2147483643;

            case KnownColor.WindowFrame:
                return -2147483642;

            case KnownColor.WindowText:
                return -2147483640;

            case KnownColor.ButtonFace:
                return -2147483633;

            case KnownColor.ButtonHighlight:
                return -2147483628;

            case KnownColor.ButtonShadow:
                return -2147483632;

            case KnownColor.GradientActiveCaption:
                return -2147483621;

            case KnownColor.GradientInactiveCaption:
                return -2147483620;

            case KnownColor.MenuBar:
                return -2147483618;

            case KnownColor.MenuHighlight:
                return -2147483619;
        }
    }
    return ToWin32(c);
}
```

It means that if you declare a Color color = SystemColors.ControlText, the ColorTranslator.ToOle(color) will return -2147483630, but if you set the color to a custom ARGB color, ColorTranslator.ToOle will return the standard ToWin32() value.